# Can I switch which egg is incubating?

Tags: pokemon-go

I started incubating a 10 km egg and I've collected 7 other eggs since then many that are 2 km and I am almost out of space. Is there a way I can switch incubation to one of the smaller eggs so I can clear my inventory faster?

Comment: I'd let you know if the servers were up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After an egg begins incubation, it may not be removed from the incubator. The only way to clear the incubator is to actually walk off the remaining distance.

Comment: It does seem to count towards my Pokemon limit as I only have 3 caught Pokemon and it says I have 10 total.

Comment: @Dom Really? I'll take a look when the servers stop crashing, but I haven't heard of that before.

Comment: It's up for me now and [this](http://i.imgur.com/cLs6gail.png) is what it currently is showing for how many Pokemon I have.

Comment: @Dom Yeah, I see. Answer edited to reflect this information.

Comment: Yes your eggs count towards your pokemon count.  If you could pause an incubator it would become and great way to farm stardust.