# Can you stop/pause egg incubation?

Tags: pokemon-go

As the title says, I started incubating a 10 km egg that I actually wanted to keep for later when I had leveled up some. Is there any way to get the egg out of the incubator for now? If so, does it reset the distance progress?

Comment: [Very similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272890/57810).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272892/76693):

> After an egg begins incubation, it may not be removed from the incubator. The only way to clear the incubator is to actually walk off the remaining distance.